# rsync fails with error: Cannot stat destination... cannot allocate memory (12)

Tags: samba, rsync, linux, server-message-block, cifs

I am trying to rsync some directories on my linux server to a Windows 7 share mounted locally on the Linux server at /mnt/backups.

My rsync command looks like this:

```
rsync -avz --progress --partial --modify-window=1 --temp-dir=/tmp /home /mnt/backups
```

When it executes I get this:

```
building file list ...
165048 files to consider
rsync: ERROR: cannot stat destination "/mnt/backups": Cannot allocate memory (12)
rsync error: errors selecting input/output files, dirs (code 3) at main.c(507) [receiver=2.6.9]
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (8 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(453) [sender=2.6.9]
```

I've searched around and the only tips I've found were to add `--modify-window` and `--temp-dir` options but those haven't made any difference.

For the record, I've had similar problems trying to tar a backup file to this mounted location which is why I wanted to switch to rsync. I suspect Samba is causing these problems but everything looks fine on the surface. Not sure what else to do from here...

Comment: Forgot to mention... the first time I ran this it went for a while, copied about 8G and then started choking on this error. Now as soon as I run the script it fails with this msg.

Comment: Are there in fact over 100,000 files? It seems the `stat` function call was unable to allocate memory, which is unusual to say the least. Also, unless the Windows machine is using the FAT filesystem, you don't need the `modify-window` option.

Answer (score 3):

Appears to be an issue on the Windows 7 end.  The fix is to update the following two reg keys.

Set the following registry key to ’1′:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management\LargeSystemCache
```

and set the following registry key to ’3′:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters\Size
```

References:
http://frankooh.wordpress.com/2012/01/02/smbrsync-cannot-allocate-memory/
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=869994&page=2&p=8251122#post8251122
http://www.decuslib.com/decus/vmslt99a/nt/tips.txt
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.windows.vista.networking_sharing/NF3jEW2VlmQ

Answer (score 0):

> Cannot allocate memory (12)

How many RAM do you have on the receiving side? Increase virtual memory on the Windows and try again.

Comment: The receiving Windows server has 12G of memory. The Linux server however only has 2G.

Comment: How about the swap on the Linux?

Comment: Linux has 2G swap

Comment: How much swap usage in `rsync`ing process? Did you try to increase it?